# Shopify checkout webhook - How to get customer email id in shopify checkout webhook response?

Tags: php, json, shopify, webhooks

I am trying to create an app in shopify which is using a chekcout webhook , everything works fine for me expect I am not able to get the email id in reponse of the webhook .

```
$checkout_information   = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

and the json respone is like

```
{

"buyer_accepts_marketing":false,
"cart_token":"0b1b8b379b7ce41617162522804d8198",
"closed_at":null,
"completed_at":null,
"created_at":"2015-01-19T23:43:33-05:00",
"currency":"PHP",
**"email":"",**
"gateway":null,
"id":426722529,
"landing_site":"/",
"note":null,
"referring_site":"",
"shipping_lines":[
],
"source_identifier":null,
"source_name":"checkout_next",
"source_url":null,
"subtotal_price":"40000.00",
"taxes_included":false,
"token":"7f337c74911a7cfc636a40472820b31a",
"total_discounts":"0.00",
"total_line_items_price":"40000.00",
"total_price":"40000.00",
"total_tax":"0.00",
"total_weight":0,
"updated_at":"2015-01-19T23:43:33-05:00",
"line_items":[
    {
        "applied_discounts":[
        ],
        "compare_at_price":null,
        "fulfillment_service":"manual",
        "gift_card":false,
        "grams":0,
        "line_price":"40000.00",
        "price":"40000.00",
        "product_id":384871021,
        "properties":null,
        "quantity":1,
        "requires_shipping":true,
        "sku":"",
        "tax_lines":[
        ],
        "taxable":true,
        "title":"bike",
        "variant_id":1002599593,
        "variant_title":"",
        "vendor":"yamaha"
    }
],
"name":"#426722529",
"note_attributes":[
],
"source":"checkout_next",
"discount_codes":[
],
"abandoned_checkout_url":"https://checkout.shopify.com/7171333/checkouts/7f337c74911a7cfc636a40472820b31a/recover",
"tax_lines":[
]
}
```

How to get a valid email id in this response

Comment: Did you try this in a real production store? Maybe you have something disabled on the checkout due to be on a test store? Alternatively, did you wait some minutes for shopify to pass all the data?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem related either to the order itself or to the type of store you're using (test store). Try this in a real production store.